# Aggregate, sort and calculate weighted average using R

Tags: r, sorting, aggregate, weighted-average

I have two dataframes. One is for invoice details(df_inv), other is for collection details (df_coll) against the invoices. 
One invoice might have multiple collections/vouchers.
Invoice table has around 30 columns, for now we are checking only 3 columns for this calculation(Invoice no, Expected Amount, Due Date)
Similarly collections table has multiple variables, for this scenario we consider 3 columns(invoice no, voucher date, credit amount)
PS: one invoice of $300 might get paid thru 3 vouchers ($100 each) on 3 different dates. Also amount credited can be lesser than or greater than expected amount.
Based on the invoice numbers (which is unique) from invoice table, I need to find its corresponding vouchers from collections table, sort it in ascending order based on the date of voucher, find the delay in payment (df_coll$VoucherDate - df_inv$DueDate), then calculate the weighted average for each invoices.

x4 in df_inv, doesnt have a corresponding entry in df_coll. Hence it will return NA

weighted avg calculation(for 1 invoice with 2 payment vouchers):

```
((1st pymt amt* 1st delay days)+ (2nd pymt amt* 2nd delay days))/((% of total credited amount)*(expected amount))
```

sample data below,

Invoice Table(df_inv)

```
Invoice No  Expected Amount Due Date   
  x1    1400    02-01-2012
  x2    850     20-04-2012
  x3    1300    30-09-2012
  x4    1500    25-01-2013
```

Collections Table(df_coll)

```
Invoice No  Voucher Date    Credit Amount
      x1    26-11-2012  100
      x2    24-10-2012  200
      x1    11-05-2012  300
      x1    22-08-2013  100
      x2    12-07-2013  500
      x3    30-01-2014  600
      x2    24-06-2012  100
      x3    31-11-2012  700
      x1    29-02-2012  800
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using only base R :

```
####################  Recreate your input data.frame's   ##################
df_inv <- 
data.frame(InvoiceNo=c("x1","x2","x3","x4"),
           Expected=c(1400,850,1300,1500),
           AmountDueDate=c("02-01-2012","20-04-2012","30-09-2012","25-01-2013"),
           stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df_coll <- 
data.frame(InvoiceNo=c("x1","x2","x1","x1","x2","x3","x2","x3","x1"),
           VoucherDate=c("26-11-2012","24-10-2012","11-05-2012","22-08-2013",
                         "12-07-2013","30-01-2014","24-06-2012","30-11-2012","29-02-2012"),
           CreditAmount=c(100,200,300,100,500,600,100,700,800),
           stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df_inv$AmountDueDate <- as.Date(df_inv$AmountDueDate,format='%d-%m-%Y')
df_coll$VoucherDate <- as.Date(df_coll$VoucherDate,format='%d-%m-%Y')
###########################################################################

m <- merge(df_inv,df_coll,by="InvoiceNo",all.x=TRUE,all.y=FALSE)
m$CrdAmntWeighted <- m$CreditAmount *  as.numeric(m$VoucherDate - m$AmountDueDate)
m$TotCredAmnt <- ave(m$CreditAmount,m$InvoiceNo,FUN=sum)
m$TotCrdAmntWeighted <- ave(m$CrdAmntWeighted,m$InvoiceNo,FUN=sum)
m$WeightedAvg <-  m$TotCrdAmntWeighted / ((m$TotCredAmnt / m$Expected) * m$Expected)

final <- m[!duplicated(m$InvoiceNo),c('InvoiceNo','Expected','TotCredAmnt','WeightedAvg')]

> final
   InvoiceNo Expected TotCredAmnt WeightedAvg
1         x1     1400        1300    137.0000
5         x2      850         800    334.8750
8         x3     1300        1300    257.6154
10        x4     1500          NA          NA
```

Comment: Thanks heaps. It helps